# Find out leak in airbed?

Tags: bedroom, air

Recently I found out that my airbed is deflating.

How can I find the leaking spot? If I put the bed in a big pool, I can find it. Unfortunately I don't have one. Any hack to find out?

Comment: @MANEESH_MOHAN, you edited my question, but what is ou means?

Comment: probably, it's out, corrected

Comment: it got missed, sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could better use method as shown:

Using soap water

- Take some soap water in a spray bottle
- Inflate your air bed to full air
- Close the nozzle
- Spray the content from bottle(start from nozzle)
- Inspect closely for air bubbles (hole will produce bubbles on applying soap water)
- Mark the spot with a marker
- You could use used chewing gum to close the spot located but you could resort to a standard method to remove this hole as question does not hold that as issue

Answer (score 1):

There are kits available to repair these beds once you locate the spot where its leaking. Using a product called Spray 9 diluted with water in a squirt bottle works good.The leak is very likely at the seam on the edges of the bed.

Some say a couple of drops of super glue on a tiny hole will fix it, but I haven't tried that method. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, as [recently discussed on Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/44455/18917), is to have your hand slightly wet and stroke the airbed in a regular pattern, so your hand covers the whole at one time or an other.
First of all, the wet hand makes it easier to feel the air. Secondly, when the hand closes over the hole, it makes a much sharper note, often also much louder, than without the hand.

When this does not work, you can use several of the other find leak in tube tricks.
You do not need to fully inflate, even less over inflate an airbed.
You can use a little air in only a small part of the bed, and have that in a basin of water which is just big enough for that part to be in, as long as you hold that part of the bed under water and under pressure.